# OAuth in pop-up with Tornado Auth TwitterMixin

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tornado

Is it possible to do the [Tornado Oauth](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/auth.html#twitter) `authenticate_redirect()` in a pop-up window, and return to main window by closing pop-up when authentication is done?  I would like to implement this, but it seems the Tornado `httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient` only will pass a completely new url to the browser.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado isn't aware of any pop-ups you're dealing with. Its just responding to http requests by sending either some kind of content such as html or redirects your browser to a new url. The pop-up behaviour you described should rather be implemented on the client side using javascript. Check out related answers for that:

[Twitter OAuth via a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878529/twitter-oauth-via-a-popup)

[Twitter oauth authorization in a pop-up instead of in main browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754869/twitter-oauth-authorization-in-a-pop-up-instead-of-in-main-browser-window)